# Ubuntu Virtual Host cant connect to MS-SQL Server

Tags: server, apache2, php, mssql

**Scenario:** 
Running laravel to connect to sql server.

It connects and works fine when the application is run from the terminal. (using php artisan serve)

But when its put up in a virtual host (test.zzz.com), it fails to connect, doesn't even show any error message.

I am guessing its some permission issue to access sqlsrv drivers maybe. Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most probably due to cached config.

Please try

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: did an apache restart and it finally worked :D